# keyword "layer" unrecognized in add_cube function

Tags: python, scripting, error

I want to execute the next piece of code:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from math import sin,cos, radians

add_cube = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add
layers = [False]*32
layers[0] = True

cursor = context.scene.cursor_location

radius = 5
anglesInRadians = [radians(degree) for degree in range(0,360,36)]

for theta in anglesInRadians:
    x = cursor.x + radius * cos(theta)
    y = cursor.y + radius * sin(theta)
    z = cursor.z
    add_cube(location=(x,y,z), layer=layers)
```

But I have an error:
[image]

I got this piece of code [from this website](https://sites.google.com/site/satishgoda/blender/learningblender25/introduction-to-blender-python-api) (see below of the page).
Is supposed the piece of code runs on version  2.5 and my version is 2.71

Why I have this error?

Comment: You may want to be aware of the [Blender Python API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/), which documents all the parameters and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for [`primitive_cube_add`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add) should be `layers` not `layer`.

You will also get an error that layers should only have 20 values not 32. I'm not certain if older versions accepted this length variation, I know it fails in blender since 2.62

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from math import sin,cos, radians

add_cube = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add
layers = [False]*20
layers[0] = True

cursor = context.scene.cursor_location

radius = 5
anglesInRadians = [radians(degree) for degree in range(0,360,36)]

for theta in anglesInRadians:
    x = cursor.x + radius * cos(theta)
    y = cursor.y + radius * sin(theta)
    z = cursor.z
    add_cube(location=(x,y,z), layers=layers)
```